# Telegram API integration of link_preview_options

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot

i try learning API telegram and i have some issue with 'Parameter' 'link_preview_options'

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

```
  function sendTelegramMessage(chatId, text) {
    var token = "my_token";
    var apiUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage";

    var payload = {
      method: "post",
      payload: {
        chat_id: chatId,
        text: text,
        parse_mode: "HTML",
        link_preview_options: {is_disabled: true},
      },
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, payload);

  }
```

I get

```
Exception: Request failed for https://api.telegram.org returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse link preview options JSON object"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
    at sendTelegramMessage(NotifyTG:17:32)


17  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, payload);
```

this parameter should remove thumbnails in links from messages sent by the telegram bot

It works without 'link_preview_options: {is_disabled: true},'

```
  function sendTelegramMessage(chatId, text) {
    var token = "my_token";
    var apiUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage";

    var payload = {
      method: "post",
      payload: {
        chat_id: chatId,
        text: text,
        parse_mode: "HTML",
        // link_preview_options: {is_disabled: true},
      },
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, payload);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed this part:

```
var payload = {
  method: "post",
  payload: {
    chat_id: chatId,
    text: text,
    parse_mode: "HTML",
    // link_preview_options: {is_disabled: true},
  },
};
```

On this

```
var payload = {
  method: "post",
  contentType: "application/json",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bot " + token
  },
  payload: JSON.stringify({
    chat_id: chatId,
    text: text,
    parse_mode: "HTML",
    disable_web_page_preview: true
  }),
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
```

Now it works and I don't know why =/